# How connect robot to DWA_local_planner

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have cloned dwa_local_planner algorithm from here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git.

Can you tell me what do I need to do to connect it to my robot and world? How does it work?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324159/how-connect-robot-to-dwa_local_planner/) by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set up complete ROS navigation stack to run dwa_local_planner on your robot: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0